# compute the mean of a range of salary in a column

Tags: python

Each row has a unique range. For example the the first row has a salary range of "20000-28000" and the dataframe is made up of 757 rows.
 I tried using the following codes but i had this error message "Length of values does not match length of index"

```
newsalary = [] 
for row in range(10):
    if row != "0":
        newrow =  df.loc[:'salary_range'].mean()
        print(newrow)
    else:
        newrow = 0
    newsalary.append(newrow)

df['salary_range'] = newsalary
```

So I tried changing the "range to 757" but it runs to infinity 
Can you please help me with the correct code to compute the mean for each row.

Comment: Can you post the result of `print(df['salary_range'].head())`?

Answer (score 0):

```
df.['salary_range'][:10].mean()
```

You can select the range that interests you using the indexing of the [python lists](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-list/):

```
df.['salary_range'][20000:28000].mean()
```